# Get a color name from any RGB combination (script included)

Tags: php, function, javascript

i am returning a hex and an RGB color in my app (from camara) and i want to use a script to identify that color and display a name... ive found 
http://gauth.fr/2011/09/get-a-color-name-from-any-rgb-combination/
script but i cant make it to work ...

my code has this script to get the rgb and hex values :

```
function color(){
 var rgb = getAverageRGB(document.getElementById('smallImage'));
    document.getElementById("r").style.background = 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')';

var x='rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')';
document.querySelector('.results').innerHTML = 'rgb('+rgb.r+','+rgb.g+','+rgb.b+')' + " hex:"+ hexafy(x); showDiv1()  ;
```

then i tryed to use the code from the script on the linked page...but with no sucess... :

```
<script>
window.classifier = new ColorClassifier();
get_dataset('js/dataset.js', function (data){
    window.classifier.learn(data);
});
var result_name = window.classifier.classify("#aaf000");
alert (result_name);
</script>
```

i also had included :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/color_classifier.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dataset.js"></script>
```

but noting happens... any clue how to use this ?

Comment: What does this have to do with WordPress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to give you a definitive answer as there's not enough detail - but if you're calling the two external resources correctly (you'll also need jQuery if you're using this method), then you should get an alert as requested. Here's a fiddle of it working correctly when you bring the resources inline (which excludes the need for jQuery) https://jsfiddle.net/j3gbwvvg/. The reason you don't need jQuery is because we're putting the data directly into a variable and calling that, not using the library's function which utilises the .getJSON() jQuery function.

```
window.classifier = new ColorClassifier();
window.classifier.learn(data);
var result_name = window.classifier.classify("#aaf000");
alert(result_name);
```